# Apply settings as machine-wide in Rider

Tags: rider

I modified some settings in Rider and I want these settings to be set globally (machine-wide), not just "For current project" as it can be seen on the image.

[image: Image of settings page]

I also tried clicking "Manage Layers", then editing the layer "This computer", but inside that I can't add new settings directly.

How do I save anything so it is saved to "machine wide" (this computer)?